# Black screen after booting Ubuntu on an Asus Zenbook Pro UX501

Tags: boot, asus

I have Ubuntu installed on an external hard drive. It was originally installed on my old laptop, but now I have a new one. When I try to boot on it, the computer seems to boot properly but there's no UI. I see a command line interface for about 30 seconds, then the screen goes black and I hear the keyring-unlock sound. Still works fine on my old laptop though.

Any clue what could be going on here? Anything I can try?

Comment: I would say it's video driver problems. Even though Ubuntu is supposed to be great with switching from one computer to another with the same installation, there will usually be some problems. Do you know what graphics card brand your old laptop has and which your Zenbook has?

Comment: Yep, turned out that this was it. I was running Ubuntu 14.04, which predates the GTX 960M (on my new computer) by about a year.